# How to Detect if an XML Element is Empty using DOMDocument in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

If I delete an element inside an element, and if its the last element, then the parent element gets shortened to an empty element.

Example:

Start:
`<element><child1>Inner HTML</child1><child2>Inner HTML</child2></element>`

I delete Child2 and I get:
`<element><child1>Inner HTML</child1></element>`

I delete Child1 and I get:
`<element/>`

Now I want that to not happen or at least a way to detect if the element is empty so I can replace it.
How can I do that using DOMDocument in PHP.

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "want that to not happen?"  What do you want to have happen instead?  What code are you using to delete the other elements?

Comment: Code should be definitely provided with this explanation. If you want to detect is element empty or not you could simply after deleting or before check http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php

Comment: actually, i found the error... it was due to something else. sorry for posting this question...

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to determine whether an element is empty by inspecting the length of the [list of child nodes](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes):

```
$isEmpty = $elem->childNodes->length === 0;
```

Note that not only elements can be child nodes of another element but also [CDATA sections](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domcdatasection), [comments](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domcomment), and [plain text](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domtext).

Comment: actually, i found the error... it was due to something else. sorry for posting this question... but thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php):

```
count($elem->children());
```

So, to check if empty:

```
$isEmpty = count($elem->children()) === 0 ? true : false;
```