# edit element if empty

Tags: php, dom, replace

The code below successfully let's me edit the div contents with php, but only if the div has content in it already, if I put content in it when the div is empty, it gives me an Error, I want to be able to edit the div even if the div is empty.

Error message:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to DOMNode::replaceChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in

```
$div_id = "div_wrapper"; // name of the div
$div_Data = "This is a list of albums";
$file = '../folders/rock/albums.php';
$doc = new DOMdocument();
$file_get = file_get_contents($file);
$doc->loadHTML($file_get);
$element = $doc->getElementById($div_id); 
$element->replaceChild($doc->createTextNode($div_Data),$element->firstChild);
$myfile = fopen($file, "w+") or die('Unable to open file!');
fwrite($myfile,$doc->saveHTML());
```

Comment: Try to use a conditional `empty()`.

Comment: @ Fred -ii , i have pasted the error message, where would empty() fit in dom

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/8668971/ could give you some ideas.